# VSCode Extension: problem matching on compiler output with blank line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Im currently writing a vscode extension for a language used with Campbell Scientific dataloggers. Part of the extension I have made specifies a custom problem matcher for the compiler results.

The issue I am having is when I send the crbasic program (test.cr300) to the compiler using a task in tasks.json, I am unable to match the file name from the top of the compiler results.

Edit: This is due to the blank line in between the filename and the error messages. I currently am unable to find a way around this. Adding \n to the pattern doesn't work as expected even though it works on https://regex101.com/.

Example of returned text from the compiler:

```
test.cr300 -- Compile Failed!
 
line 12: Undeclared variable U1. 
line 18: gmx600 not yet declared so cannot be aliased. 
line 19: gmx600 not yet declared so cannot be aliased. 
line 20: gmx600 not yet declared so cannot be aliased. 
line 21: gmx600 not yet declared so cannot be aliased.
```

Pattern as specified in my package.json:

```
 "pattern": [
                {
                    "regexp": "^(.*\\.cr300).*\\n$",
                    "file": 1
                },
                {
                    "regexp": "^line\\s(\\d+):\\s(.+)$",
                    "line": 1,
                    "message": 2,
                    "loop": true
                }
            ]
```

and here is my task from tasks.json when running the extension in debug.

```
        {
        "label": "CRBasic: Compiler",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "powershell.exe"
            }
        },
        "command": "${config:CRBasic.Path.Compiler path}\\cr300comp.exe",
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$crbasicCompiler"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After narrowing down the issue to a blank line, the below pattern now problem matches the compile output. In hindsight it seems obvious. Thanks to @rioV8 for the help.

```
"pattern": [
                {
                    "regexp": "^(.*\\.cr300) -- Compile Failed.*$",
                    "file": 1
                },
                {
                    "regexp": "^.*$"
                },
                {
                    "regexp": "^line\\s(\\d+):\\s(.+)$",
                    "line": 1,
                    "message": 2,
                    "loop": true
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of the regexes and add a `loop` attribute and change the group number for `line` and `message`

```
"pattern": [
    {
        "regexp": "^(.*\\.cr300) -- Compile Failed.*$",
        "file": 1
    },
    {  "regexp": "^\\s*$"  },
    {
        "regexp": "^line\\s(\\d+):\\s(.+)$",
        "line": 1,
        "message": 2,
        "loop": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks rioV8. I did find the info on the loop and made the changes as suggested. Still no match on the file name.

Comment: @g0atm1lk in the doc they have all regex with `^$` so I have modified the answer

Comment: The issue lays with the blank line between test.cr300 and the first error message. If I fudge some output with no blank line it matches as expected, as soon as I add the empty line it fails.  Unfortunately I cant find a way around this, simply adding \n to the pattern doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @g0atm1lk : Add a regex that will recognize the empty line, or line with white space